# JQuery Datatables not showing its data

Tags: json, datatables

Here's my JSON data:

```
{
    "0": {
        "counthigh": 33,
        "loc": "Barangay 7",
        "countmedium": 25,
        "countlow": 31
    },
    "1": {
        "counthigh": 27,
        "loc": "Barangay 6",
        "countmedium": 31,
        "countlow": 15
    },
    "2": {
        "counthigh": 17,
        "loc": "Comagascas",
        "countmedium": 38,
        "countlow": 10
    },
    "3": {
        "loc": "Barangay 3",
        "countmedium": 3,
        "countlow": 16
    }
}
```

I want it to be used in my datatables, so far tried this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var tbl_barangay = $('#jsontable_brgy').dataTable();
     $.ajax({
         url: 'tbl/',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (s) {
             tbl_barangay.fnClearTable();
             for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                 tbl_barangay.fnAddData([
                 s[i]['locat'],
                 s[i]['countlow'],
                 s[i]['countmedium'],
                 s[i]['counthigh']]);
             }
         },
         error: function (e) {
             alert(e);
         }
     });
 });
```

It doesn't show anything on the table and no error has been thrown. Any help? I've been figuring it out but fails.

Comment: What have you tried? You may need to convert the string to a JSON object with  data = JSON.parse(s);

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. I can't get the values from JSON data.

Comment: What does the rest of your datatable object look like?  Most of the time you point datatables to an existing html table, give it a url on the sAjaxUrl prop, or do things server side. In whichever one you use the actual data should be part of a larger object that also has info for the paging, filtering, etc.

Comment: updated the question, the problem is I can't get the data.

Comment: A doesn't have a length, it's an object not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to loop through an `Object` as if it were an `Array`.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var tbl_barangay = $('#jsontable_brgy').dataTable();
     $.ajax({
         url: 'tbl/',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(s) {
             tbl_barangay.fnClearTable();
             for (var key in s) {
                 if (s.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                     var obj = data[key];
                     tbl_barangay.fnAddData([
                         obj['loc'] || 0,
                         obj['counthigh'] || 0,
                         obj['countlow'] || 0,
                         obj['countmedium'] || 0
                     ]);
                 }
             }
         },
         error: function(e) {
             alert(e);
         }
     });
 });
```

Since you're using data tables, I think you're making hard work of this - datatables offers this functionality out of the box - http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html
Your data structure is just a little off.

Here's a working demo doing it your way (you are also missing a property on "3", which I've added in the below):

```js
var data = {
  "0": {
    "counthigh": 33,
    "loc": "Barangay 7",
    "countmedium": 25,
    "countlow": 31
  },
  "1": {
    "counthigh": 27,
    "loc": "Barangay 6",
    "countmedium": 31,
    "countlow": 15
  },
  "2": {
    "counthigh": 17,
    "loc": "Comagascas",
    "countmedium": 38,
    "countlow": 10
  },
  "3": {
    "loc": "Barangay 3",
    "countmedium": 3,
    "countlow": 16,
    "counthigh": 3,
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  var tbl_barangay = $('#jsontable_brgy').dataTable();
  tbl_barangay.fnClearTable();

  for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var obj = data[key];
      tbl_barangay.fnAddData([
        obj['loc'],
        obj['counthigh'],
        obj['countlow'],
        obj['countmedium']
      ]);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="jsontable_brgy">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>High</th>
      <th>Medium</th>
      <th>Low</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually that missing data is from a query. Is there a way for datatables to accept null value or if it is blank then assign it to '0'.

Comment: Figures! Thanks! Actually, I did change my query.